# Is P = { <M,w> | M rejects w} the complement to Atm = { <M,w> | M accepts w}?

Tags: turing-machines

As Atm is recognizable, its complement cannot be recognizable, due to being so Atm would be decidable.

I am trying to clarify if the problem P is the complement to Atm.

If so, how could i approach the problem without looking at Atm to prove undecidability?

My first thought was:

> H is a machine which solves P:
>
> H halts and accepts when M rejects w.
>
> H halts and rejects when M accepts w.

And from then on contradict the construct like in the proof of Atm.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question in the title (is $P$ the complement of $A_{tm}$) depends on several issues. To see why, let's start by computing the complement of $A_{tm}$:
$$
\overline{A_{tm}} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle : M \text{ does not accept } w \} \cup \{ x : x \text{ is not of the form } \langle M,w \rangle \}.
$$
If you choose an encoding for $\langle M,w \rangle$ for which there exist strings which are not of the form $\langle M,w \rangle$, then $P$ is definitely not the complement of $A_{tm}$. However, there do exist encodings in which you can decode *any* string into a Turing machine and an input string. In that case,
$$
\overline{A_{tm}} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle : M \text{ does not accept } w \}.
$$
You are asking whether this is the same as
$$
P = \{ \langle M,w \rangle : M \text{ rejects } w \}.
$$
The question is how you define acceptance and rejection. Here is one possible definition:

> A Turing machine *accepts* an input if it halts on an accepting state. It *rejects* an input if it halts on a non-accepting state.

Under this definition, there is also a third option: the Turing machine never halts. So $P$ and $A_{tm}$ are not complements of each other. Here is another definition:

> A Turing machine *accepts* an input if it halts on the input. Otherwise it rejects it.

Under this definition, $P$ and $A_{tm}$ are complements of each other. If you define the language of a Turing machine as the set of strings it accepts, then both definitions are equivalent (you can modify a Turing machine to fit either), but the exact choice does matter for your particular question.

Answer (score 1):

It is a common misunderstanding among students that if a Turing machine does not accept its input, then it will reject it. But a Turing machine may loop forever on some inputs. On any given input $w$, a Turing machine may

- accept $w$
- reject $w$
- or loop forever

So the complement of $A_{\mathsf{TM}}$ is

$$\overline{A_{\mathsf{TM}}} = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid M \text{ is a Turing machine that does not accept } w \}$$